# Как в Wordpress минимизировать количество запросов wp_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется некая главная страница сайта, на ней через определенный промежуток текста вставляется в контенте шоткод, который вытягивает определенные первые 3 записи, не важно какого посттайпа, получается в каждом из трех мест идет апрос базу wp_Query, так вот, интересует можно ли как-то минимизировать количество запросов в базу данных, мб в вордпрессе есть какие-то инструменты для этого? Вот на картинке будет видно лучше, о чем речь:
[image: home page structure]

Comment: Вы шутите? 3 запроса в базу вас волнуют? WP на тяжелых сайтах исполняет сотни запросов при загрузке страницы, и ничего.

Comment: KAGG Design, Окей, пара вставок то ничего) Но хотелось бы все таки узнать имеются ли решения данного вопроса, даже не в плане wp, а php-сайтов если к примеру у меня будет 50 таких вставок, в каждой из них есть еще дополнительные 1-2 запроса, как-то оно не по феншую со стороны, чтобы к примеру я мог после первого запроса куда-то сохранить данные, а потом смотреть если запрос уже делался такой, то берем его сохраненный результат

Comment: Ну, во-первых, WP все кеширует на нескольких уровнях. Будьте уверены, что если вы повторяете запрос, то получите результат из кеша. Во-вторых, можете взять одним запросов все ваши посты на странице, а потом уже из массива постов выводить.

Comment: Смысла в даном действии особого нету, но если надо сократить количество запросов на 1 в пользу шорткода, то можно написать микро функцию по логике:

1. Посчитать количество вставок шорткода в контенте.

2. Вытащить типи постов нужные, если они отличаются.

3. Сформулировать запрос WP_Query со всеми нужными постами, и их сортировкой.

Дале просто отредактировать вывод блоков для темплейта.

Как видите гемороя предостаточно, но выполнимо.